# Regex expressions for extracting data from String xml?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a xml document with `<name>Doe, John (Jim)</name>`

I get the xml as a string and want to extract the value in between these tags

Kindly suggest what regex to use for the same ?.

thanks

Comment: Don't use regex. Gah.

Comment: Can you give 1 more example ?

Comment: *Why* do you think you need a regular expression? Why can't you use an XML API? It's the only *sensible* approach, IMO. If you have some *really good* reason then that should be included in the question. Never ask a question where the obvious answer is "Don't do it that way" without explaining why you need to do something odd.

Comment: this is not a xsd validated xml and may change over time so just need boiler plate code in java to get that value

Answer (score 0):

For your example,

```
<name>Doe, John (Jim)</name>
```

this regular expression

```
>(\w+\,\s*\w+\s*(\(\w+\))*)<
```

catches

```
Doe, John (Jim)
```

Comment: Thanks apgp88, also i was looking at some more ways to do this
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<name>(.+?)</name>");
  Matcher m = p.matcher("<name>Doe, John (Jim)</name>");

  if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
  }

Comment: This above snippet from a post seems to be working too, @apgp88 u see any issues with above snip ?.

Comment: Snip in the comment ?